# How to extract digits (number) using Matlab

Tags: matlab, png

At work I have to record a lot of data from png data. Every time I have to manually record the digits (e.g. `mean\SD 101.1\11`) on the excel sheet and read it with Matlab. Would it be possible that Matlab could directly read the digits from the PNG image, so that lots of work could be saved?

I know it might involve pattern recognition, but still hope that there may be someone who has done this before.

Comment: Please post an example png file.

Comment: Are the digits machine or human generated?  are they always the same font or different fonts?  OCR techniques exist all over the place, your ease of use/success will depend greatly upon the answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Optical Character Recognition (OCR). The code for it is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition--ocr-)